# Typesetting curiosity: word change on one line does not affect how that line is set, but affects how the next line is set

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, paragraphs, typography

The following two paragraphs differ only in that the first one uses "his" on the first line and the second one uses "her".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\RequirePackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\textwidth5.5in

\begin{document}

Each producer \(j\), when choosing the output of his production unit (an element in \(T(j)\))
takes as given the price system \((p_1,p_2)\) prevailing in the market and maximizes the value
of this output (the unit's profit).

Each producer \(j\), when choosing the output of her production unit (an element in \(T(j)\))
takes as given the price system \((p_1,p_2)\) prevailing in the market and maximizes the value
of this output (the unit's profit). 
\end{document}
```

TeX sets the paragraphs like this:
[image]
The linebreak for the first line is the same in both paragraphs, but the linebreak for the second line differs between the paragraphs.  Thus the difference in the first lines doesn't affect the way the first line is set, but affects the way the *second* line is set.  Why does TeX's paragraph-setting mechanism do that?

Comment: Interesting... What TeX engine (`pdftex`, `xetex`, `luatex`,...) and distribution/version are you using? I couldn't reproduce that with neither engine in TeXLive 15, 18, 19, and 20.

Comment: I'm using BaKoMa version 11.50 (e-TeX version 3.14159265-2.6).  Not sure whether than answers your question.

Comment: Ah, BaKoMa is WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get). I'd change that acronym to WYSMBWYWG,BNN (What You See Might Be What You Will Get, But Not Necessarily). There is a lot of things going on under the hood of a program like that, which is _not_ done by TeX, and since the program is not open source, you can't tell what it does. If you compile that using a TeX engine, both lines will probably look the same.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case (very likely it's not), but TeX attempts to create lines with a similar spacing. If spaces in the first line are shrinked, it can think the second line is best typeset with less spacing.

Comment: @JavierBezos I would say too that this is the cause. TeX typesets *paragraphs* so a change in badness of one line can affect another one.  (I can't reproduce the output either so can't use `\tracingparagraphs` to check. I also get a different hyphenation, so quite probably bakoma has some special settings.)

Comment: This is not at all impossible as tex tries to avoid having one tight line next to another loose line, but to check please add `\tracingparagraphs=2` and show the log that you get.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The sense in which BaKoMa is "WYSIWYG" is pretty much the same as the sense in which every other TeX processor with a preview capability is WYSIWYG.  It's just that when you edit the TeX code in BaKoMa, the preview instantly recompiles, whereas in other systems you have to press a special key to induce the recompilation.  (In BaKoMa you can also edit the TeX code by typing in the Preview window, which is often extremely convenient.)

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne The key issue is “instantly recompiles”. TeX cannot instantly recompile: it can only run a document top to bottom and show the entire thing. Everything else are emulations (some better, as it seems to be the case with BaKoMa, and some not so good). But as David points out in his answer, TeX does produce that output, but with a slightly different input, so BaKoMa seems to have a specific version of _something_ (a package, a TeX engine, etc.) that makes for the difference in input.

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne I would actually be interested to know what bakoma tex is doing on your original, I had to make `her` a _lot_ wider (and modify the hyphenation) before getting a different break in that text so the bakoma setup must be using different fonts, I think?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What information from the log file do you need to determine that?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik If you are looking at page n of a document and make a change on that page, it's necessary only to recompile the document up to page n.  And generally a change in page n doesn't affect previous pages, so the recompilation can be fast.  (If it _does_ affect previous pages, BaKoMa can be very slow.)  When you scroll to page n+1, that page is compiled.  So it is possible to "instantly" (or at least extremely quickly) recompile what is needed to show the part of the document visible on the screen.

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne probably all of it, with `\tracingall`  (you could mail it to me, my gmail account  is easily findable if you google my name  but `d`  dot `p` dot `carlisle` at  `gmail` dot `com` basically

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne Not necessarily. If you take a paragraph out from a page, the next page will probably change. The previous pages are less likely (but still possible: table of contents, being an example) to change. But then, all of this is speculation based on what I know of TeX: I have no idea what bakoma does. I'd like to see David's analysis.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sure the next page will change, but you don't need to compile that until the user scrolls to that page.  BaKoMa definitely recompiles on every keystroke: you can watch the compilation happening in TeX log in the Console window.  (Another example in which a change on a page affects _previous_ pages is when you have overlays in Beamer slides.  Then BaKoMa can be quite slow --- but it is definitely recompiling and displaying the result as you type.)  BaKoMa does not "emulate" the compiled output, but simply displays it.

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne Well, I couldn't possibly know that, as I don't have it installed. It seems to be a rather elaborate system...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I added some notes on the differences. The actual tex run is pretty much standard texlive 2016/2017 by the look of the log, I think the preview updating cleverness is mainly on the previewer side.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I could not reproduce the output that you show, however by exaggerating width of `her` I can produce the effect,

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\RequirePackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\textwidth5.5in


\lefthyphenmin=3
\tracingparagraphs2

\begin{document}

Each producer \(j\), when choosing the output of his production unit (an element in \(T(j)\))
takes as given the price system \((p_1,p_2)\) prevailing in the market and maximizes the value
of this output (the unit's profit).

Each producer \(j\), when choosing the output of he\vrule width7.01pt r production unit (an element in \(T(j)\))
takes as given the price system \((p_1,p_2)\) prevailing in the market and maximizes the value
of this output (the unit's profit). 
\end{document}
```

TeX tries to avoid having a very loose line next to a very tight one. In order to get `and` on to the second line the white space has to be very compressed and that isn't allowed in the first paragraph but  with the wider `her` in the second form, the white space in the first line is compressed enough to allow the tight second line.

The log shows

First paragraph:

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
[]\T1/mdput/m/n/12 Each pro-ducer $\OML/mdput/m/it/12 j$\T1/mdput/m/n/12 , when
 choos-ing the out-put of his pro-duc-tion unit (an ele-
@\discretionary via @@0 b=0 p=50 d=2600
@@1: line 1.2- t=2600 -> @@0
ment in $\OML/mdput/m/it/12 T\OT1/mdput/m/n/12 (\OML/mdput/m/it/12 j\OT1/mdput/
m/n/12 )$\T1/mdput/m/n/12 ) takes as given the price sys-tem $\OT1/mdput/m/n/12
 (\OML/mdput/m/it/12 p[]; p[]\OT1/mdput/m/n/12 )$ \T1/mdput/m/n/12 pre-vail-ing
 in the mar-ket 
@ via @@1 b=28 p=0 d=1444
@@2: line 2.1 t=4044 -> @@1
and 
@ via @@1 b=86 p=0 d=9216
@@3: line 2.3 t=11816 -> @@1
max-i-mizes the value of this out-put (the unit's profit). 
@\par via @@2 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@\par via @@3 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@4: line 3.2- t=4144 -> @@2
```

second paragraph

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
[]\T1/mdput/m/n/12 Each pro-ducer $\OML/mdput/m/it/12 j$\T1/mdput/m/n/12 , when
 choos-ing the out-put of he|r pro-duc-tion unit (an 
@ via @@0 b=102 p=0 d=22544
@@1: line 1.0 t=22544 -> @@0
ele-
@\discretionary via @@0 b=38 p=50 d=4804
@@2: line 1.3- t=4804 -> @@0
ment in $\OML/mdput/m/it/12 T\OT1/mdput/m/n/12 (\OML/mdput/m/it/12 j\OT1/mdput/
m/n/12 )$\T1/mdput/m/n/12 ) takes as given the price sys-tem $\OT1/mdput/m/n/12
 (\OML/mdput/m/it/12 p[]; p[]\OT1/mdput/m/n/12 )$ \T1/mdput/m/n/12 pre-vail-ing
 in the mar-
@\discretionary via @@1 b=9 p=50 d=12861
@@3: line 2.2- t=35405 -> @@1
ket 
@ via @@1 b=4 p=0 d=10196
@ via @@2 b=28 p=0 d=11444
@@4: line 2.1 t=16248 -> @@2
and 
@ via @@2 b=86 p=0 d=9216
@@5: line 2.3 t=14020 -> @@2
max-i-mizes the value of this out-put (the unit's profit). 
@\par via @@3 b=0 p=-10000 d=5100
@\par via @@4 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@\par via @@5 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@6: line 3.2- t=14120 -> @@5
```

---

---

---

---

Martin sent me a full `\tracingall` log of the document in the question, run through Bakoma TeX, so that I could investigate why I needed to add the rule to make `her` wider.....

Comparing  a `\tracingall` log of the original  version, the LaTeX in the bakoma tex run advertises itself as

```
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
```

I actually got the fewest differences using texlive 2016, but there the main difference appears to be slight differences in the mathdesign package setup

In particular the diff of the logs shows

**tl2016**

```
Package: mathdesign 2013/08/29 v2.31 Math Design Project
...
{select font mdputr8t at 11.28003pt}
...
OT1/mdput/m/n -><->s*[0.94]mdputr7t
```

**bakoma**

```
Package: mathdesign 2006/01/29 v1.55 Math Design Project
...
{select font mdputr8t at 11.03998pt}
...
OT1/mdput/m/n -><->s*[0.92]mdputr7t
```

so a .02 difference in scale factors used in the fonts. After that of course it is not surprising that in a particularly sensitive paragraph like this where two possible linebreaking options have similar badness and just the width difference between his and her tips the balance that a small difference in font size meant that I had to adjust the word widths to see the same effect.

Answer (score 23):

As an addition to existing answers, the idea is as follows.

TeX classifies lines in a paragraph as

1. tight
2. decent
3. loose
4. very loose
5. overfull/underfull

according to their *badness*, which is computed by looking at how much interword spaces have to be stretched or shrinked for obtaining justification; the names should be self-explanatory.

The algorithm for dividing paragraphs into lines takes the badness of each possible line into account because it works on the *whole* paragraph. The final result will be so that consecutive lines don't differ by more than one degree according to the table above. So there will be no loose line next to a tight one, nor a very loose one next to a decent one.

If there is no way to obtain the result, you'll get a warning of underfull box or, in some cases, overfull box: this happens if there is no way to break the paragraph respecting the stated tolerance.

The result is that changing a word in the *first* line of a paragraph might even influence the *last* one: if the first line changes from decent to tight, say, this may propagate.

Comment: It's not possible that a change only in line 1 can leave the linebreak between lines 1 and 2 at the same place and also leave line 2 unchanged, but change the setting of line 3, is it?  If TeX looks only at adjacent lines, then the fact that line 2 is the same in both cases means that line 3 has to be set the same, too, doesn't it?

Comment: @MartinJ.Osborne Right, I'll change the wording.